# Windowing System for .NET Console

Tags: c#, .net, console, window

Does anyone know of any simple .NET windowing systems for the console?

I'm looking for something that manages areas of the console such that they are automatically scrolled independently of other areas. For example, I could create a status strip down the bottom and a main content area above it. It would also be useful if it handled colors for me.

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen one of those since we were doing monochrome debugging on Windows 3.1,  Sounds like a fun old-school project.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A while back I took a look at [MonoCurses](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses) and [Curses#](http://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/). I don't think MonoCurses supports independent scrollable areas, but I feel like Curses# should.

I wanted this style interface so I could have one interface for windows and linux. In the end I just went with a normal command line interface.

Comment: Thanks. MonoCurses looks interesting but seems way overkill for what I need. Really all I want is a simple abstraction over the buffer copying feature in the Console class. I have a number of console-based tools supporting my project and it would be helpful in giving them a half-decent interface.