# Console Application With Multiple Panels

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application, windows-console

I'm writing a C# TCP Server as a console application,
my requirement is to display few information in separate panels in same console, like this image bellow

[image: screenshot downloaded from internet]

Is this possible to achieve in C#? if it is possible sample code will be very helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? Display a complex gui in console project ? This is a common question, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595514/windowing-system-for-net-console

Comment: [Google is your friend.](https://www.google.de/search?q=c%23+console+draw+frame&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=pMNBVrD1IoOjsAHShYCgCw) The first hits should take you all the way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve an [ncurses-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) interface in C# by using [MonoCurses](https://github.com/mono/mono-curses/).